# Add newline or carriage return directly in a column to separator values in Postgres

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, select, newline

I have the following query:

```
SELECT id,
concat_ws(', ',
            case when isBlue then 'Blue' end,
            case when isMale then 'Male' end,
            case when isAdult then 'Adult' end) as Person1,
concat_ws(', ',
            case when isBrown then 'Brown' end,
            case when isFemale then 'Female' end,
            case when isAdult then 'Adult' end) as Person2          
from misc_table  
where id <> NULL 
order by id
```

Which would output the following

```
| id | Person1             | Person2
----------------------------------------------
| 1  | Blue, Male, Adult   | Brown, Female, Adult
----------------------------------------------
| 2  | Blue, Male, Adult   | Brown, Female, Adult
```

However, I would rather have it display as:

```
| id | Person1             | Person2
----------------------------------------------
| 1  | Blue,               | Brown,
|    | Male,               | Female,
|    | Adult               | Adult 
----------------------------------------------
| 2  | Blue,               | Brown,
|    | Male,               | Female,
|    | Adult               | Adult
```

Could not seem to find a simple way to achieve this. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use some C-style escapes in string literals if you use `E''` strings, from the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE):

> **4.1.2.2. String Constants with C-style Escapes**
>
> PostgreSQL also accepts "escape" string constants, which are an extension to the SQL standard. An escape string constant is specified by writing the letter `E` (upper or lower case) just before the opening single quote, e.g., `E'foo'`. (When continuing an escape string constant across lines, write E only before the first opening quote.) Within an escape string, a backslash character (`\`) begins a C-like *backslash escape* sequence, in which the combination of backslash and following character(s) represent a special byte value, as shown in Table 4-1.

So you could say:

```
SELECT id,
concat_ws(E',\n', ...
-- -------^^^^^^
```

That will give you some `+` signs in the `psql` output though:

```
| id | Person1             | Person2
----------------------------------------------
| 1  | Blue,              +| Brown,          +
|    | Male,              +| Female,         +
|    | Adult               | Adult 
...
```

but that's just `psql` telling you that there is a multi-line column value.

BTW, `id <> null` doesn't do what you might think it does, you almost certainly want to say `id is not null` to get sensible results.

Comment: I'm guessing the C-style approach is faster/more effecient vs. the using the CHR(10) method directly in the query, as it is lower level?

Comment: I think you'd be hard pressed to find a measurable difference between them. Almost every programmer on the planet will know what `\n` means so `E',\n'` is probably more readable.

Answer (score 7):

You can force a newline character by calling `chr`:

```
SELECT id,
concat_ws(',' || CHR(10), -- HERE
            case when isBlue then 'Blue' end,
            case when isMale then 'Male' end,
            case when isAdult then 'Adult' end) as Person1,
concat_ws(',' || CHR(10), -- And HERE
            case when isBrown then 'Brown' end,
            case when isFemale then 'Female' end,
            case when isAdult then 'Adult' end) as Person2          
from misc_table  
where id IS NOT NULL -- BTW, note that nulls should be evaluated with the IS operator
order by id
```

Comment: Not a criticism, but I would suggest to anyone using this to add a comment indicating `CHR(10), -- newline character` so future devs don't have to look up this magic value (doing a reverse search for character codes is not fun)

Comment: @AaronLS +1! Frankly, I'd document any query that isn't a straight forward `select * from my_table where some_column = 'some_value'`, but all the more so in a situation like this.